# PHP Mail to Link

Tags: php, html, mailto

HI all just a quick thing. My page is throwing up an HTML 500 error when I boot up but I can't see whats wrong with my code at all. I am trying to create a contact form on my webpage that will simply take the details and email them to me when the user clicks the form. The page will simply not load with this code.

```
            <form method="post">

                <input type="text" name="contact-name" placeholder="Name." required>
                <input type="email" name="contact-email" placeholder="Email." required>
                <input type="text" name="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject." required>
                <br><br>
                <textarea name="contact-content"></textarea>
                <div id="contact-btn-wrap">
                    <input type="submit" name="contact-submit" id="login-btn-signup" value="SEND EMAIL">
                </div>

            </form>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <div class="contact-me">danashton89@gmail.com | 07714709250</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-img">
            <img src="/uploads/Portfolio/Level_Design/Unreal_Engine/Ice_Cove/icecastle_3.png">
        </div>


        <?php

            $contact-name = "";
            $contact-email = "";
            $contact-subject = "";
            $contact-content = "";

                if (isset($_POST['contact-submit'])) 
                {
                    $contact-name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact-name']);
                    $contact-email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact-email']);
                    $contact-subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact-subject']);
                    $contact-content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['contact-content']); 

                        $to = "danashton89@gmail.com";
                        $subject = $contact-subject;
                        $txt = $contact-content;
                        $headers = "From: " . $contact-name . "<br>" . $contact-email . "\r\n";
                        $headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
                        $headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";

                    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
                }

        ?>
```

Comment: There's no `mailto:` link anywhere. Anyway, check your server error log to see what's causing the 500 error.

Comment: You can also keep removing code until it works. Then you'll have narrowed it down to the problematic code. Kinda basic troubleshooting really.

Comment: Why are you using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` when you're putting the strings into email, not a database query?

Comment: `mailto:` opens the mail application on the client, it doesn't send mail from the server.

Comment: `syntax error, unexpected '='`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you cannot declare vars in php with '-'

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression, it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Second, your connection var is defined?

Last, can you provide the error string?

Comment: Thankyou been a while since Ive worked with PHP was simply the variables.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use dashes in your variables names ($contact-name ...)